# lifecycle event state and prevState in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is a simple counter in react. But I have 3 questions.

1. What is state in line 3? It looks like a global variable, it would make sense if it has `var` or `const` before it. Is that a lifecycle function/var?
2. Do I have to import Component from react? I remember I did not need do that in v15.
3. Where does prevState come from?

> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
>
> class Counter extends Component {
>   state = { value: 0 };
>
>   increment = () => {
>     this.setState(prevState => ({
>       value: prevState.value + 1
>     }));
>   };
>
>   decrement = () => {
>     this.setState(prevState => ({
>       value: prevState.value - 1
>     }));
>   };
>
>   render() {
>     return (
>       <div>
>         {this.state.value}
>         <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
>         <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
>       </div>
>     )
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a demo with a commented-out code to give you more information: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/rrGWjm

**1. What is state in line 3? that look like a global variable, it make
    sense if it has var or const before it. Is that a lifecycle
    function/var?**

`state` in line 3 is just a property of the Counter component. Another way of  initialising a state in React using ES6 syntax is as follows:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    value: 0
  }
}
```

React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

> The [React ES6 class] API  is similar to React.createClass with the exception of
>   getInitialState. Instead of providing a separate getInitialState
>   method, **you set up your own state property in the constructor**.

**2. Do I have to import Component from react? I remember I
    need not to do that in v15.**

You can alternatively just import React and define a class in the following way:

```
import React from 'react';

class Counter extends React.Component {
...
```

The below would also allow you to use Component API:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
...
```

**3. Where does prevState come from?**

The prevState comes from the setState api: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

> It's also possible to pass a function with the signature
>   function(state, props). This can be useful in some cases when you want
>   to enqueue an atomic update that consults the previous value of
>   state+props before setting any values. For instance, suppose we wanted
>   to increment a value in state:

```
this.setState(function(previousState, currentProps) {
  return {
     value: previousState.value + 1
  };
});
```

You will often see developers updating state in the following way. This is less reliable than the above method as state may be updated asynchronously and we should not rely on its values for calculating the next state.

```
 this.setState({
   value: this.state.value + 1 // prone to bugs
 });
```

Full code from my codepen:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {

  // state = { value: 0 };

  // you can also initialise state in React
  // in the constructor:
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 0
    }
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value + 1
    })); 
  }

  decrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value - 1
    }));  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: ah this is so clear thanks! means the no.1, the author did not do it 'properly' ? it's ok in my option if he do `const state = {'value':0}`

Comment: I've just added the proper way to initialise the state to my answer, under question 1.

Comment: I saw that, are you saying the author did it the wrong way? what u mean by properly? I know setting a constructor is the common way to do stuff.

Comment: When I said properly, I meant 'according to React docs': https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes which say  "you set up your own state property in the constructor". I've just added this to the answer.

Comment: Though it also works if you set the initial state as a property in the class body (at least in some code I have made using "Create React App" cli), but probably because of some ES6+ features like found in ([https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus]https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus)

Comment: Good to know. I will be checking this out. Thanks Diego.

Comment: "Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state." So using a function with previousState is a better approach according to React

Answer (score 3):

There are some features in your code that are related with the ES6 (ES2015) version, so that's why you might be confused:

> What is state in line 3? that look like a global variable, it make sense if it has var or const before it. Is that a lifecycle function/var?

As it is inside a `class` body, this is not a global variable. In this case `state` is a property that will be set to the instances of `Counter`, so you could access that by `this.state`.

> Do I have to import Component from react? I remember I need not to do that in v15.

When creating a component using a class, you need to extend the `Component` class, so in this case: yes you need to import `Component` or you could've used `class Counter extends React.Component` as well.

> Where does prevState come from?

Again, a ES6 feature. What is being passed to the `this.setState()` method is a **function**. It might be confusing because this is a *arrow function `=>`*. So `previousState` is actually a parameter of that function. To help you to see the picture, the above code is *similar*  to that:

```
this.setState(function (prevState) {
  return {
    value: prevState.value - 1
  };
});
```

There are some differences between 'normal' and an arrow functions, though, so I suggest you to search for the ES6 features in order to be more familiar with it.

Comment: usually what people do is do `const variableName = {propsName:'something}`