# How would you write this without using arrow notation?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

In my increaseCount method I have 3 different ways of increasing the count. I thought the first method could be used twice but it doesn't work as it seems to merge the setState in the callback.  What's the proper way to use a callback function and why does the arrow notation work?  How is prevState.count being defined? It is never set to 0

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  increaseCount() {
    console.log(this);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count }, function() {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    });

    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });

    this.setState(prevState=>({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.increaseCount()}>Increase</button>
        </div>
        <h2>{this.state.count}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```
this.setState(prevState=>({count: prevState.count + 1}))
```

Comment: use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) to convert es6 to es5 syntax/

Comment: @DCR it does work check my codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.setState(function (prevState) {
  return {count: prevState.count + 1};
});
```

> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrRzgB?editors=1011

Both prevState and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with prevState.

> setState(updater[, callback])

Comment: where is prevState.count being defined?  where is it set to 0?

Comment: In the constructor

Comment: the constructor doesn't say anything about prevState

Comment: you can add `!prevState.count ? 0 : prevState.count + 1` if there may not be an inital state

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806802/lifecycle-event-state-and-prevstate-in-react-js  prevState is passed from react you can get (prevState, currentProp) you can name them anything its the same as when you get passed an event on a click handler in vanilla js

Comment: Both prevState and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with prevState. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: anything else i can help with?

Comment: is prevState the same as this.state?

Comment: exactly but its always up to date and less likely for bugs from typos ect :)

Answer (score 2):

```
this.setState(function(prevState) {
  return {count: prevState.count + 1};
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: have you bound this to the function setting the state