# How to update my initial state in redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

Hi I have this user list container that render also the user form container.
I just put both containers in an if that in the initial page load the user list will be display.
After clicking the add user button the user form will be displayed.

How can I change the state isAddUser from my reducers when I click the isAddUser button.?

```
addUser(){
    //button to show add user form 
    //update the reducers initial state isAddUser
}

if(this.props.isAddUser){
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="container table-responsive">
                <UserForm/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
} else {
    return(
             <div className="row">
                <div className="container table-responsive">
                    <div className="text-right"> 
                        <button 
                            className="btn btn-primary text-right"
                            onClick={this.addUser.bind(this)}>
                            Add User
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <table className="mt-1 table table-hover">
                        <thead className="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>                
                        {userList}  
                    </table>
                </div>    
            </div> 
          )
      }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    users: state.users.items,
    isAddUser: state.users.isAddUser
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUsers, deleteUser })(UserList);
```

reducers

**I need to update isAddUser: false to true from initialstate**

```
import { FETCH_USERS, DELETE_USER } from '../actions/User/Types';

const initialState = {
   items: [],
   item: {},
   isAddUser: false
}
export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_USERS:
          //code here

        case DELETE_USER:
          //code here

        default: 
           return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create new action called `UPDATE_ADD_USER`.
when you call this action update variable.

```
case UPDATE_ADD_USER:
        return {...state, isAddUser: true};
```

Create action like `fetchUsers, deleteUser` then send it in actions list.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUsers, deleteUser,updateAddUser })(UserList);
```

In `addUser` function

```
addUser(){
   this.props.updateAddUser();//call new action created
}
```

Comment: I need to update isAddUser: false to true when I click Add User Button

Comment: what is the action type when you are updating `isAddUser` ?

Comment: i still dont have. Since Im new in react. I need advise on how to do it.
I have this button <button className="btn btn-primary text-right"  onClick={this.addUser.bind(this)}>Add User</button>

Comment: How to construct action on that @amruth ?

Comment: check how you are importing fetchusers follow the same

Comment: So when I need to update the isAddUser to false .. i need to create again an action? Can I just reuse the action and just pass a parameter like true or false?

Comment: pass parameter, when you want to update just take prevstate and reverse it and update current state. have a look at -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806802/lifecycle-event-state-and-prevstate-in-react-js/39807012

Comment: Can you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477055/how-can-i-dispatch-function-in-redux