# React "forgets" state when using debounce function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is a question for someone who understands React/RN better than I. When I wrap touchable components (i.e. buttons) in a lightweight wrapper with a debounce function (to prevent onPress handler from being called too rapidly), it usually works as intended. HOWEVER, in a very specific set of circumstances, things go awry. If I pass a parent component's state down into the onPress prop of the button, if the state property I'm accessing has been destructured in the render method and then passed as this variable, rather than simply accessed as this.state.foo, the onPress handler reads it as its initial state value, even if it has been updated. This is probably confusing so allow me to show you a quick, incomplete example:

```
class DebounceButton extends Component {
    handlePress = debounce(this.props.onPress, 500)
    render() {
        return (
            <Button onPress={this.handlePress}
        )
    }
}

class Screen extends Component {
    state = {
        foo: 0
    }

    render() {
        const { foo } = this.state
        return (
            <Button onPress={() => {this.setState({ foo: this.state.foo + 1 })}}/>
            <DebounceButton onPress={() => {console.log(foo)}}/>
            <DebounceButton onPress={() => {console.log(this.state.foo)}}/>
        )
    }
}
```

If I press Button, foo increments to 1. If I then press the first DebounceButton, the console will log 0. If I press the second, it will log 1 as it should. Note it only happens when state is passed through the debounce function AND assigned to a variable in the render method. It's as if React is "forgetting" what the current state is and default to its initial value. This is no longer a bug for me as I'm not using this debounce paradigm anymore, but I'm curious to understand it to better so I can have a better grasp on the way React works. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: setState has an updater that has access to prevState and newState. Leveraging that similar to how this answer does https://stackoverflow.com/a/39807012/793330 might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class property `handlePress = debounce(this.props.onPress, 500)` will only be evaluated when `DebounceButton` is first created, so changing the `onPress` after it has first been rendered does not work.

You could instead create a new function that invokes `this.props.onPress` inside of it. This way the current value of `this.props.onPress` will be used every time.

```js
class DebounceButton extends Component {
    handlePress = debounce(() => {
        this.props.onPress();
    }, 500);

    render() {
        return <Button onPress={this.handlePress} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! So why is it that my previous method worked when passing in this.state.foo but not a previously destructured foo? Is it because React is listening for changes in state and applies them everywhere that this.state is referenced? And since foo has been destructured this no longer occurs because it's no longer tethered to state?

Comment: @kevbot You're welcome! `() => {console.log(foo)}` is initially `() => {console.log(0)}` because `foo` is `0` when that function is created and is never changed in `DebounceButton` since it just uses the initial function. `() => {console.log(this.state.foo)}` evaluates `this.state.foo` when it is called and therefor gets the correct value, the same way the `handlePress` in my answer is implemented.