# Using prevState for counter functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure where I'm going wrong but I have two buttons that act as a counter

```
this.state= { currentQuestionId: 1 }
```

Depending on the state of `currentQuestionId`, it renders specific divs

I have this function

```
checkButton = button => {
    if (button.id === 3) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        userAnswers: state.userAnswers.concat([button]),
        currentQuestionId: (state.currentQuestionId = 5),
      }))
      console.log('questionState', this.state.currentQuestionId)
    } else {
      this.selectAnswer(button)
    }

    console.log('button pressed', button.id)
  }
```

If a specific button is pressed, it sets `currentQuestionId = 5`,

I also have another function that decreases `currentQuestionId`

```
previousQuestion = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ currentQuestionId: prevState.currentQuestionId - 1 }))
  }
```

Basically, once my `CheckButton function` fires, it sets my `currentQuestionId = 5`, and when `previousQuestion` fires, I want it to return the state of `currentQuestionId` before it was set to 5

What am I missing?

Comment: Why is 5 - 1 supposed to be 4?

Comment: Are you saying that when you set `currentQuestionId = 5`, then run `previousQuestion`, that `currentQuestionId` is set to `4`?

Comment: @jarrad_obrien Yup, however instead of`  `currentQuestionId` -1, I would like to use `prevState.currentQuestionId` -1

Comment: `currentQuestionId: (state.currentQuestionId = 5)`. What is this supposed to do? Why do you have parentheses here? You are setting state directly by saying `state.currentQuestionId = 5`. It should be `currentQuestionId: 5` if you want to set it to 5.

Comment: prettier puts parentheses, I don't think its affecting the output.  the checkButton function is not the issue here. I'm referring to the previousQuestion function, I want it to return the state of `currentQuestionId` before it was set to 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're understanding `prevState` to mean the value that a state was in before it was changed to another value. For example, you're expecting that if `currentQuestionId = 3`, then we set `currentQuestionId = 5`, that `prevState` of `currentQuestionId` is equal to 3. This isn't what `prevState` is used for.

`prevState` allows you to perform an atomic update on a value to ensure correctness:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ currentQuestionId: prevState.currentQuestionId - 1 }))
```

Whereas using `this.state` is performed asynchronously:

```
this.setState(() => ({ currentQuestionId: this.state.currentQuestionId - 1 }))
```

However, these both reduce `currentQuestionId` by 1. More info regarding the usage of `prevState` and how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806802/lifecycle-event-state-and-prevstate-in-react-js).

To answer your question, what you want to do is to add another state variable to your class called `previousQuestionId`, and set that to `currentQuestionId`, before updating `currentQuestionId` to a new value. That way you can keep track of the previous value and set it using this:

```
previousQuestion = () => {
    this.setState({ currentQuestionId: this.state.previousQuestionId }))
  }
```

EDIT: A better way to track the previous questions is to use a stack. You can push new values to it when a new question ID is selected, and pop values off of it when you run `previousQuestion`.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer, really appreciate it. Will definitely check out a stack solution too